# Moving performance summary data from a strategy in pine script

Tags: tradingview-api

I would like to be able to take the results from a strategy in TV and be able to organize the results from backtesting many stocks. Currently I can only export data one stock at a time. Simply being able to export a file to excel with the columns being the list of symbols and then the info provided on the overview page would be amazing.

I have looked all over the web trying to find out how this is accomplished.

Any way possible to obtain summary information on a group of symbols or all symbols would be great. My goal is to be able to organize the stocks by how well the strategy performed on them.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this within TV. Only way I'm aware of would be scraping.